# creating a habitat suitability map with thresholds

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, terra

I am trying to create a habitat suitability map for a species in NZ but want it to show the scale above a threshold as opposed to a heat map for all the areas.

So I have taken the habitat suitability of a location where they have been observed in NZ and made that the threshold and everything below that is marked as 0, this produces a map that looks almost like what I want but it starts filling in the heat map at darker colours indicating a high level of suitability. I want it to be scaled so that the areas that only JUST got over the threshold are lighter. When I put the values below the threshold as NA, the scaled heatmap works but wverything(including the background of the panel) is greyed out. I have tried overlaying a geom_sf of NZ but that didn't work either. Here is the code/ section I am working on.

```
# lon/lat
observed <- matrix(c(175.6521, -37.9501), nrow = 1)

# get HS score
observed_hss <- terra::extract(y2, observed )

# convert HS map to binary 
binary_raster <- ifel(y2 < observed_hss[1,1] - 0.05, 0, y2)

terra::writeRaster(binary_raster, "binary_rast.tif", overwrite = T)

# crop the binary from the nz map

non.nz <- terra::crop(binary_raster, nz_map, mask = T) ## this didn't work as desired either


binary_p <- ggplot() +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_sf(data = nz_map) +
  geom_spatraster(data = binary_raster,
                  maxcell = 3e5,
                  interpolate = T) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = get_pal("caw_seq_4"))  +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0.01)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0.01)) +
  labs(fill = "Habitat \nsuitability",
       x = "Longitude",
       y = "Latitude") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible approaches.

Example data

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)  / 574
```

Use "breaks"

```
cols <- c(gray(0.95), rev(viridis::viridis(5)))
plot(r, breaks=c(0, .5, seq(.6, 1, 0.1)), col=cols)
```

[image]

Exclude areas, plot on top of a background

```
cols <- rev(viridis::viridis(50))
plot(r, col=gray(.95), legend=FALSE, mar=c(3.1, 3.1, 2.1, 7.1))
plot(r, range=c(.5, 1), add=TRUE, col=cols)
```

[image]